# jQuery add class to first item until another is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to add a .current class to series of thumbnails that's built into a wordpress plugin. I'm not familiar with MooTools so I'm trying to use jQuery to add the .current class. What I'm looking to do is add the .current class to the first thumbnail div and remove the class after another is clicked.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$('div.thumb img').click(function() {  // When we click on something in the filter menu
        $(this).css('outline','none'); // Remove css outline
        $('div.thumb').removeClass('current'); // Removes the current class from where it is now
        $(this).parent().addClass('current'); // Adds the current class to the item we clicked on
    return false;
});
```

This does add the class in after an item is clicked but the initial thumbnail isn't highlighted. So I'm trying to set the intial thumbnail so it has a .current class until another thumbnail is clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: might help
http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: Could you produce a sample on `jsfiddle` and show what you want to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On dom read you need to get the first thumb element and then add the `current` class to it.

```
$(function(){
    $('div.thumb:first').addClass('current')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

put this in `doc ready`:

```
 $('div.thumb').first().addClass('current')
```